# Dynamic permanent property for Tooltip leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to show a tooltip when a `Legend` component get hover. For that I have a `Father` component that has an `useState` hook in order to pass to the Leaflet `Map` component the index for an array `Location` and change the `Permanent` property if these index are equal.

`const permanent = i === showLocationPosition;`

The `showLocationPosition` is the index for the location that is getting hover, getting by props for its `Father` component.

```js
<Marker
  position={[position[0], position[1]]}
  key={index}
  icon={divIcon({ className: 'marker-dot dot-hover', html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(stringHTML), iconSize: [30, 30] })}
>
  <Tooltip direction="bottom" opacity={1} offset={new Point(xPoint, 10)} permanent={permanent}>
    <div className={`popup-container-header ${item.count ? 'w-80' : 'w-40 text-center'}`}>
      <p className="w-full">
        {type_of_country_operation ?? item.name}
      </p>
      {item.count && <p>{item.count}</p>}
    </div>
    {item.summary && <p className="popup-container-main">{item.summary}</p>}
  </Tooltip>
</Marker>
```

I could validate that the `permanent` variable changes but the `Tooltip` does not apear.

Any advice ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the change in `permanent` doesn't help is because underlying leaflet options are [treated as *immutable*](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components#props) by react-leaflet.  So even as your `showLocationPosition` might change (which changes `permanent`), the Tooltip was already created and will not respond to changes in that prop.

A quick and dirty way would be to use the `key` prop on the tooltip *also*, which can be a combination of the index and the permanent status:

```js
<Tooltip {...otherProps} key={`${index}-${permanent}`}>
```

This would force a rerender of that Tooltip component when the value of permanent changes.

I would consider a different approach. If you don't need to *also* render the Tooltip when you mouseover the `Marker` it originates from, just conditionally render it based on `permanent`:

```js
<Marker {...markerprops}>
  {permanent && <Tooltip direction="..." offset={...} permanent={permanent}>
    {stuff}
  </Tooltip>}
</Marker>
```

You may want to change the name `permanent` to something else, like `currentOpenTooltip`.  Now, if you *also* want to have the tooltip open and close properly when the user mouses over a marker, you'll need to add a condition for that.  You can use a state variable to keep track of what `Marker` is being moused over, and use event handlers to control that state variable.

```js
const Father = () => {

  const [currentlyMousedOverMarker, setCurrentlyMousedOverMarker] = useState(-1);

  return (
    <MapContainer>
      {markersData.map((marker, index) => {
        <Marker 
          {...markerprops}
          eventHandlers={{
            mouseenter: () => { setCurrentlyMousedOverMarker(index) },
            mouseleave: () => { setCurrentlyMousedOverMarker(-1) }
          }}
        >
          {permanent || currentlyMousedOverMarker === index && 
            (
              <Tooltip permanent={permanent || currentlyMousedOverMarker}>
                {stuff}
              </Tooltip>
            )
          }
        </Marker>
      })}
    </MapContainer>
  )

}
```

Obviously this code example is simplified and doesn't contain any of the logic you already had for `permanent`, but its just to give you an idea that the tooltip should only be rendered if *either* condition is true.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer, I'm testing following your advice and I will let you know.

Comment: In my case I have to use the dirty option, since I had more than one tooltip that could get fire in the map. Thanks for this answer, it really helps !

Comment: On second thought, the 'quick and dirty' way is probably the best way